# Loading Model only once in fastAPI

Tags: python, tensorflow, fastapi

I have a Deep learning model and i want to load that model only once when my api start.
Right now model is loading for every request made in my api service with the test image, and it is taking fair bit of time to print an output.

I tried loading my model with fastapi @app.on_event('startup')

```
main.py
@app.on_event('startup')
def init_data():
    print("init call")
    model = load_model(model_path)
    return model
```

and I want to import this model variable to another python file classification.py

```
#classification.py
pred = model.predict(image)
```

I am not sure if this is the correct way to do this. Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can load the model on the root level of `main.py`; the main use of the startup event is for easier testing and, if async, requiring the function to finish before any requests will be handled. In sync code on the root of the main file it should work out of the box. Another option is to have a dictionary defined in root, then populate that dictionary inside your startup function, as shown in the reference manual: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/

Comment: @MatsLindh I did tried your first suggestion of loading model at root level but i was not able to import the model variable declared at main.py root level to my prediction file i.e classification.py

Answer (score 2):

So what you need, it is just to encapsulate this in some functions and pass the model along.

```py
# main.py
import classification
# Other imports...

model = load_model(model_path)
# Model is global so loaded once.


# ...

@app.get('/whatever/page')
def predict(image):
    global model   # We make sure model is not local
    # We call classification's predict function
    result = classification.predict(image, model) 

    #...
```

```py
#classification.py
# import ...

# The function predict takes the model as a param, and the image to predict.
def predict(image, model):
    pred = model.predict(image)
    # ...
    return pred
```

You should do this better with typing of the parameters, etc.  but that gives an idea of the dataflow. Another approach would be to load the model in the root of `classification.py` so you don't need to pass it along. That will be executed only once when imported the first time.

Comment: Thanks for your response @vinalti i will try this and if possible can you please elaborate on what u meant by typing of the parameters.

Comment: I mean to follow the recommendation of FastAPI, with python typing on function parameters, exemple : `def myfunc(txt:str, val:int, arr=List[int])`

Comment: i tried your way but it doesn't solved my problem. see what i am doing is i take a zip file from the front end and save its path along with flag=1(which denote file is not processed yet), and i have a scheduler function running separately which will check the database if there exist any row with flag 1, if there is then it will pick the zip file from theat path, unzip it, and then call classification.py file

Comment: Can you be more descriptive on what doesn't work ? Is the model reloaded everytime ? how do you see it ?

Comment: hi it worked after loading the model in the root of classification.py, Thanks and one more doubt. is there any way i can run my scheduler.py file as soon as my api service start. Right now using two terminal 1. uvicorn main:app --relaod and 2. python scheduler.py     i want my scheduler file to run as soon as uvicorn main:app --reload command execute.

Comment: you can create a script to start both of them at once, or you can dockerize you application.

Comment: Thanks @vinalti for the response, fastapi's start_up solved my problem

Comment: @Blackfly Nice to hear ! could you describe it in an answer to your own question ? That may be useful for others.